# Flutter build ios failing: identifier Xcode.IDEKit and other errors

Tags: xcode, flutter, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I have a Flutter project that I have rewritten from scratch given the breaking changes of Flutter v3 and Firebase core.

It now builds and runs on Android without any trouble, and up to a few weeks ago was running in the ios simulator on iOS13.

However over the past few weeks I have been unable to build the ios app, or get it to run in the simulator. The errors I am getting are rather cryptic and never ending, and it is hard to see what is just a warning and what is actually breaking.

I am now stuck with the following confusing message and I am unable to figure out where or what is wrong. The things I have googled (eg identifier Xcode.IDEKit errors) all end in dead-ends or simply recommendations to reinstall everything, which I don't have the strength to do again! Anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Note: XCode v13.4, Flutter v3.3.10, MacBook Pro (MacOS 12.5 Monterey)
Flutter doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Error messages:

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ A new version of Flutter is available!                  │
│                                                         │
│ To update to the latest version, run "flutter upgrade". │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Changing current working directory to: /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             21.3s
Running Xcode build...
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        26.7s
Xcode build done.                                           1347.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2023-01-31 19:49:03.384 xcodebuild[73078:8328367] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    2023-01-31 19:49:03.385 xcodebuild[73078:8328367] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/tg/wkq_y0195v5fkm57j908f33h0000gn/T/flutter_tools.qPudq7/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirZJqB8J/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    /Users/samheyman/Code/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:13: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    /Users/samheyman/Code/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:48: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                                                   ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/samheyman/Code/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:13: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    /Users/samheyman/Code/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-4.4.0/ios/Classes/LocationPlugin.m:176:48: warning: 'UIAlertView' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 9.0 - UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Location is Disabled"
                                                   ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/location/location-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIAlertView.h:27:12: note: 'UIAlertView' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface UIAlertView : UIView
               ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m:148:42: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:_appStoreURL];
                                             ^~~~~~~
                                             openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOSCustomBrowser.m:156:61: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      BOOL openedInBrowser = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
                                                                ^~~~~~~
                                                                openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:53:3: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      SFAuthenticationSession *_authenticationVC;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:143:7: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC =
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:144:37: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
              [[SFAuthenticationSession alloc] initWithURL:requestURL
                                        ^~~~~
                                        ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:180:58: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        openedUserAgent = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
                                                             ^~~~~~~
                                                             openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:203:3: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC = _authenticationVC;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    5 warnings generated.
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:53:3: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      SFAuthenticationSession *_authenticationVC;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:143:7: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
          SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC =
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:144:37: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
              [[SFAuthenticationSession alloc] initWithURL:requestURL
                                        ^~~~~
                                        ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:180:58: warning: 'openURL:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
        openedUserAgent = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:requestURL];
                                                             ^~~~~~~
                                                             openURL:options:completionHandler:
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/AppAuth/AppAuth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:124:1: note: 'openURL:' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    - (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL*)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("openURL:options:completionHandler:", ios(2.0, 10.0)) NS_EXTENSION_UNAVAILABLE_IOS("");
    ^
    /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:203:3: warning: 'SFAuthenticationSession' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 12.0 [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      SFAuthenticationSession *authenticationVC = _authenticationVC;
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      ASWebAuthenticationSession
    In module 'SafariServices' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/AppAuth/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m:25:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SafariServices.framework/Headers/SFAuthenticationSession.h:48:12: note: 'SFAuthenticationSession' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @interface SFAuthenticationSession : NSObject
               ^
    5 warnings generated.
    /Users/samheyman/Code/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4.2.5/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:103:72: warning: sending 'FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<FLTFirebasePlugin> _Nonnull'
        [[FLTFirebasePluginRegistry sharedInstance] registerFirebasePlugin:self];
                                                                           ^~~~
    In module 'firebase_core' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4.2.5/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:7:
    /Users/samheyman/Code/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-2.4.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.h:23:64: note: passing argument to parameter 'firebasePlugin' here
    - (void)registerFirebasePlugin:(id<FLTFirebasePlugin> _Nonnull)firebasePlugin;
                                                                   ^
    /Users/samheyman/Code/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4.2.5/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:1937:45: warning: 'keyWindow' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected
    scenes [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
                                                ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_auth/firebase_auth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:135:51: note: property 'keyWindow' is declared deprecated here
    @property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly) UIWindow *keyWindow API_DEPRECATED("Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes", ios(2.0, 13.0));
                                                      ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:135:51: note: 'keyWindow' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/samheyman/Code/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4.2.5/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:103:72: warning: sending 'FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin *__strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<FLTFirebasePlugin> _Nonnull'
        [[FLTFirebasePluginRegistry sharedInstance] registerFirebasePlugin:self];
                                                                           ^~~~
    In module 'firebase_core' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4.2.5/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:7:
    /Users/samheyman/Code/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-2.4.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.h:23:64: note: passing argument to parameter 'firebasePlugin' here
    - (void)registerFirebasePlugin:(id<FLTFirebasePlugin> _Nonnull)firebasePlugin;
                                                                   ^
    /Users/samheyman/Code/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-4.2.5/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:1937:45: warning: 'keyWindow' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected
    scenes [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      return [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
                                                ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_auth/firebase_auth-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:135:51: note: property 'keyWindow' is declared deprecated here
    @property(nullable, nonatomic,readonly) UIWindow *keyWindow API_DEPRECATED("Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes", ios(2.0, 13.0));
                                                      ^
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator15.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:135:51: note: 'keyWindow' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/samheyman/Code/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-4.3.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.m:490:29: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types ('FIRQuery *' and 'NSNull * _Nonnull') [-Wcompare-distinct-pointer-types]
      if (query == nil || query == [NSNull null]) {
                          ~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/samheyman/Code/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-4.3.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.m:490:29: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types ('FIRQuery *' and 'NSNull * _Nonnull') [-Wcompare-distinct-pointer-types]
      if (query == nil || query == [NSNull null]) {
                          ~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/samheyman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gqzyzivottaphbgvxjaodyrqvvit/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/Script-90FF83C039AA3D5206949481.sh: line 2: /Users/samheyman/Code/minipass-v2/minipass/ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols: No such file or
    directory
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/tg/wkq_y0195v5fkm57j908f33h0000gn/T/flutter_tools.qPudq7/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirZJqB8J/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro.
```

Answer (score 0):

After weeks of trial and error the following steps fixed the issue:

1. Make a backup of the ios folder (if not using Git)
2. Delete the ios folder
3. Run `flutter clean`
4. Run `flutter create .` from the app root directory, this will recreate a new ios folder
5. Add the Podfile, Info.plist and any other such files from the old ios folder back to the new ios folder (eg. GoogleService_info.plist)
6. Run `flutter pod install`
7. Run `flutter run` or `flutter build ios` and it should work

source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/100161 (answer by AshfaqAshi)

I tried several other suggestions from StackOververflow, Apple Developers, etc but none worked:

- Cleaning Flutter directory and rebuilding (`flutter clean`,`flutter pub upgrade`, etc)
- Upgrading GoogleMaps (error in XCode)
- Running `xcrun` commands in the command line (e.g. `xcrun -sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path`)
- Adding the SDK path to my `.zshrc` file
- Downgrading XCode from 13.3 to 13.2
- Adding a line in the Podfile to handle a bug in XCode 13.3 regarding the 'DKImagePickerController/PhotoGallery'